# Am I having an issue in my Mix!!

Tags: mixing

Ok so this is not technically sound design but I ened technical ears and you guys are the best for that.

Just produced a track recently and a have had positive feedback from allot of people. However one has mentioned that they care hear distortion/clipping throughout the whole track and its unlistenable to the point of after 10 seconds having to stop.

I am not sure I understand what the issue is so thought I would get another perspective from some guys that work with audio.

http://soundcloud.com/myinvisiblesound/jupiter

Comment: If the reviewer stopped after ten seconds, how does he or she know that the distortion lasts through the whole track?

Comment: I feel they may been over dramatising as I know he has listend to the whole track a few times.  This person is someone who's opinion I really trust and have done for many years, I think this style of music is just really not his cup of tea and was not being his usually subjective self lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andrew

I think you just got an overly negative review. I hear that there is a synth part what has a distortion element to it. This to me is a creative choice.  I don't hear anything technically wrong here.

Comment: Thanks Chris, some times when you work on a sound for so long even the errors can sound like part of the mix so fresh ears are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew

I agree with the comment above, just sounds like the low end synth line has a clip to it, all personal preference, nothing to worry about at all, would suck if we all produced squeaky clean pop songs, keep going buddy !